# Getting Warning Message when running SQL script on IBM DB2

Tags: db2

I'm using IBM DB2 on cloud and selected `Run SQL` to create a script. After creating the script, I obtain the following warning message and I'm not able to see any results:

> *Commands Running:
>   SQL commands are currently running. You can wait or cancel the current commands to run commands again.

Comment: The message is saying that the script is not yet finished, so you either wait for it to complete, or you can cancel it.   Are you using the FREE plan?

Answer (score 0):

You should only get that message when a query is running in the console from the Run SQL page.

If you can't see a query running in the console which you can cancel, then that might indicate an issue with the console (maybe clear your cookies and re-login, or raise a support case if you are on a paid plan).

You should also be able to open a new tab and run a 2nd query.